# Will hadoop be faster than mySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am facing a big data problem. I have a large MySQL (Percona) table which joins on itself once a day and produces about 25 billion rows. I am trying to to group together and aggregate all the rows to produce a result. The query is a simple join:

```
--This query produces about 25 billion rows
SELECT t1.colA as 'varchar(45)_1', t2.colB as 'varchar(45)_2', count(*)
FROM table t1
JOIN
table t2
on t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY t1.colA, t2.colB
```

The problem is this process takes more than a week to complete. I have started reading about hadoop and wondering if the map reduce feature can improve the amount of time to process the data. I noticed HIVE is a nice little add-on to allow SQL like queries for hadoop. This all looks very promising, but I am facing an issue where I will only be running on a single machine:

```
6-core i7-4930K
16GB RAM
128 SSD
2TB HDD
```

When I run the query with MySQL, my resources are barley being used, only about 4Gb of ram and one core is only working 100% while the other are working close to 0%. I checked into this and found MySQL is single threaded. This is also why Hadoop seems to be promising as I noticed it can run multiple mapper functions to better utilize my resources. My question remains is hadoop able to replace MySQL in my situation in which it can produce results within a few hours opposed to over a week even though hadoop will only be running on a single node (although I know it is meant for distributed computing)?

Comment: I'm just wondering (not an answer to your question) but just wondering aloud here... why is this resultset needed? What question is this resultset designed to answer? What problem does this query solve? (The most efficient query is the one that isn't run.)

Comment: It is a weather dataset. In a simple form, it will output the number of times a location had the same on high and low temperature on the same day within a margin essentially (there is a bit more to it than just high and low, but it is the jist of it). In the end I would like to get all the places which have the same high and low temps on the same day (this produces about 25 billion places) and would like to have a resultset of which places met this criteria more than N times

Comment: You might check out [Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/sql/).  Runs on a cluster or on a single machine across multiple threads.

Comment: @climbage - This looks very interesting. I have just read the documentation, but is it possible to do joins?

Comment: Yes you can do joins, but you may have to write a bit of code.  Your use case seems pretty straight forward

Answer (score 3):

Some very large hurdles for you are going to be that hadoop is really meant to run on a cluster and not a single server. It can make use of multiple cores but the amount of resources that it will consume will be very significant. I have a single system that I use for testing that has hadoop and hbase. It has namenode, secondary name node, data node, nodemanager, resourcemanager, zookeeper etc running. This is a very heavy load for a single system. Plus HIVE is not a true SQL compliant replacement for a RDBMS so it has to emulate some of the work by creating map/reduce jobs. These jobs are considerably more disk intensive and use the hdfs file system for mapping the data into virtual tables (verbage may vary). HDFS also has a fairly significant overhead due to the fact that the filesystem is meant to be spread over many systems.

With that said I would not recommend solving your problem with Hadoop. I  would recommend checking out what it has to offer though in the future.

Have you looked into sharding the data which can take advantage of multiple processors. IMHO this would be a much cleaner solution.

http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/01/parallel-query-mysql-shard-query/

You might also look into testing postgres. It has very good parallel query support built in.

Another idea is you may look into trying an olap cube to do the calculations and it can rebuild the indexes on the fly so that only changes will be taken into affect. Due to the fact that you are really dealing with data analytics this may be an ideal solution.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation on why hadoop is probably not the right answer for me! I am completely new to OLAP, but will read about it

Answer (score 2):

## Hadoop is not a magic bullet.

Whether anything is faster in Hadoop than in MySQL is mostly a question of how well your abilities to write Java code (for mappers and reducers in Hadoop) or SQL are...

Usually, Hadoop shines when you have a problem running well on a single host, and need to scale it up to 100 hosts at the same time. It is *not* the best choice if you have a single computer only; because it essentially **communicates via disk**. Writing to disk is not the best way to do communication. The reason why it is popular in distributed systems is crash recovery. But you cannot benefit from this: if you lose your single machine, you lost everything, even with Hadoop.

Instead:

1. **figure out if you are doing the right thing**. There is nothing worse than spending time to optimize a computation that you do not need. Consider working on a subset, to first figure out whether you are doing the right thing at all... (chances are, there is something fundamentally broken with your query in the first place!)
2. optimize your SQL. Use multiple queries to split the workload. Reuse earlier results, instead of computing them again.
3. reduce your data. **A query that is expected to return 25 billion *must* be expected to be slow!** It's just really inefficient to produce results this size. Choose a different analysis, and double-check that you are doing the right computation; because most likely you aren't; but you are doing much to much work.
4. build optimal partitions. Partition you data by some key, and put each date into a separate table, database, file, whatever, ... then process the joins one such partition at a time (or if you have good indexes on your database, just query one key at a time)!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right MySQL is single threaded i.e. 1 thread per query.
Having 1 machine only I don't think it will help you much because you may utilize the cores but you will have contention over I/O since all threads will try to access the disk.
The number of rows you mentioned are a lot but you have not mentioned the actual size of your table on disk.
How big is your table actually? (In bytes on HD I mean)
Also you have not mentioned if the date column is indexed. 
It could help you if you removed the `t2.colB` or removed the GROUP BY all together.
GROUP BY does sorting and in your case it isn't good. You could try to do the group by in your application.
Perhaps you should tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve with your query. May be there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes the table has indexes and it is using the memory engine. When I export the table to csv it takes about 2.5 GB of space. I am planning on creating a RamDisk to store the csv which hadoop could read from. I forgot to mention something very important and that is that I would like hadoop to only output rows which have a count of N greater (I estimate 95% of the rows will be removed due to this and it will produce only about 5% of the rows in the final output, maybe even less)

Comment: I tried doing the aggregation using java using TROVE hashmaps, but after about a few 100,000,000 enteries into the maps they would have serious collision performance issues.

Comment: You are using the Memory storage engine?That is not a disk based storage engine. The data are all in-memory. If you remove the GROUP BY is it significantly faster?

Comment: Yes, the table fits into memory no problem and yes without group by the query is lightning fast. I also tried using percona's XtraDB, but the same slow result occurs.

Comment: If you remove `, t2.colB` from the GROUP by is it still fast?

Comment: no it is still very slow. As well, I need the second group by for the proper count to display

Comment: In your query the problem is that you are using the wrong storage engine. It uses hash indexes and as a result you can not get the data sorted from the index.

Comment: Can you change to use BTREE instead?

Comment: I tried using B-tree indexes which did not help. I also tried using TokuDB engine and utilizing fractal tree indexes, but again, no speed difference.

Comment: I think it is just a MySQL limitation. Before the GROUP BY function there is probably 400 billions rows of data it has to sort through to obtain the 25 billion rows. I don't think there is much more speeding up I can do with MySQL which is why I looked at Hadoop as an alternative

Comment: I am not sure about that. 2.5GB of data are not so much. And you have not said how big is each row

Comment: The result will contain two columns each with 45 characters and a count field which will be an integer less than 255.

Comment: The table is 2.5 GB. When I run the join the resultset produces a csv of more than 1.5 TB (This is before I filter the counts)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similarly large query and was able to take advantage of all cores by breaking up my query into multiple smaller ones and running them concurrently. Perhaps you could do the same. Instead of one large query that processes all dates, you could run two (or N) queries that process a subset of dates and write the results into another table.

i.e. if your data spanned from 2012 to 2013

```
SELECT INTO myResults (colA,colB,colC)
SELECT t1.colA as 'varchar(45)_1', t2.colB as 'varchar(45)_2', count(*)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 on t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t1.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.colA, t2.colB

SELECT INTO myResults (colA,colB,colC)
SELECT t1.colA as 'varchar(45)_1', t2.colB as 'varchar(45)_2', count(*)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 on t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t1.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.colA, t2.colB
```

Comment: Will I have to run multiple instances of MySQL to be able to run multiple queries at the same time or is there another way?

Comment: @user2924127 you'll only run 1 instance of the server but each query will (automatically) spawn its own mysql process

Comment: I will give this a try later today, was there a significant improvement when you ran your query by using multiple queries?

Comment: So I tried this method and it has been running for about 7 hours now and it does not seem to be close to finishing so I am stopping it now. I ran it over 6 queries and a lot of swap space was occurring so it seems I was bottle necking at memory. Ideally I would like to process all of this within 5 hours.

Comment: @user2924127 assuming you've already indexed and tuned your server, I think it will be difficult to reduce the time from 7+ days to 5 hours on a 6 core machine because we're not changing the execution speed at which each core processes data. a reasonable expectation is 7/6 or approximately 2 days (assuming you have enough ram for each core which it sounds like you don't). hadoop actually has a slower execution speed than mysql (but can farm out the work to more computers) so I don't think you'll have much luck there if your goal is to run this on a single machine